# How would you test a python script that uses os import and creates new folders etc?

Tags: python, python-3.x, testing

I'm not sure if there is a nice way to test something like this but maybe you know one:

I have written a python script that looks for changes (files added) within some given directories and if it detect added files, it runs a subprocess() on them  which takes 1 to 2 hours. Then it moves files, deletes and renames folders etc.

Now I'm sick of testing it manually every time I add some changes, but I also have no clue how to test this using autotests. Does anyone has an idea?

Thanks!

Comment: Look at unit testing for Python - you can write a setup for a group of tests, creating some files and folders in a temporary location and the unit tests will then execute one by one; each test can perform some operation and then verify the expected result is reflected on the test files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First step is to [unit-test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unit_testing) your different functions, this can be done with the built-in [unittest-framework](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.html). To do unit-testing efficient you first need to separate different functionality into different functions/units if this is not already done. I.e. you should have one function that checks for changes, and nothing else. And one function that renames folders and nothing else e.t.c.

Then when running the unittest you test isolated function, for example the function detecting changes. This is done on dummy/mock-directories that is preferably created by the test-script in the beginning and then deleted when it is done. And since you only test the function that detects changes, it is not dependent on your slow subprocess and would therefore be very quick to run. Then you have another unit-test for testing moving, deleting, renaming e.t.c. When you have a complete set of unit-test you know that you separate functions/units works as expected.

You should then regularly run your unit-tests, preferably automatic every-night or at every change. Doing this you will catch bugs quickly and make them easier to fix.

Example:

```
import unittest
from my_module import hasDirectoryChanged

class CheckDirectoryChangesTestCase(unittest.TestCase):
    def setUp(self):
        createMockDirectory(dirName)

    def test_detect_when_change(self):
        addChangesToMockDirectory(dirName)
        self.assertTrue(hasDirectoryChanged(dirName))

    def test_no_detect_when_no_change(self):
        self.assertFalse(hasDirectoryChanged(dirName))

    def tearDown(self):
        removeMockDirectory(dirName)
```

Next step is to [Integration-testing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integration_testing). This can be done in various ways in python but the most important is to automate it!

Comment: Thank you! I already have different functions for each thing to do. But how do I test removing, renaming etc? Do I need to add folders using python and test if they are removed afterwards?

Comment: I've updated my answer with example code. Basically, in the unittest-framework you have setUp and tearDown functions where you can create/remove your directory that you are testing. These functions are run before/after each test-function (test_detect_when_change, test_no_detect_when_no_change).

Comment: Thanks! The ```createMockDirectory()``` function is your own function or can it be imported from somewhere?

Comment: `createMockDirectory()` is something you have to create your self